# Can anyone please tell me what these old white 4x4 circles are?

Tags: part-identification

What are these?

[image]

They are from a box of very old LEGO bricks, circa 1981.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like 3 of [Turntable 4 x 4 - Old Type Complete, Perfectly Round](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3404bc01) which came in [13 different sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3404bc01&in=S) from 1963 - 1970.

[image: part picture]

I'm guessing the one in the middle is either broken or disassembled (if that's possible), and the top of it attached to the bottom of one on the right.